# JS trouble in computing a value from a table column and writing to another, from text input to textarea

Tags: javascript, for-loop, objectid

I can't find what is wrong in my code, as it does nothing...

my js has:

```
function calc()
{
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("cost"+i).value=        (document.getElementById("pret"+i).value*document.getElementById("cant"+i).value)*1.24;
        document.biblioteca.total.value+=document.getElementById("cost"+i).value;
    }

}
```

and the html is:

```
<form name="biblioteca">
<table width=600 border="3">
    <tr>
        <th width="50%">Carte</th>
        <th width="15%">Pret</th>
        <th width="15%">Cantitate</th>
        <th>Cost(TVA inclus)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Manuscrisul gasit la Accra - Paulo Coelho</td>
        <td id="pret1" value="20">20</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" id="cant1"></td>
        <td><textarea name="cost1" id="cost1" rows="1" value=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Poarta coliviei - Katie Hickman</td>
        <td id="pret2" value="10">10</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" id="cant2"></td>
        <td><textarea name="cost2" id="cost2" rows="1" value=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cincizeci de umbre ale lui Grey - E.L. James </td>
        <td id="pret3" value="44">44</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" id="cant3"></td>
        <td><textarea name="cost3" id="cost3" rows="1" value=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ciresarii. Vol.2: Castelul Fetei In Alb - Constantin Chirita</td>
        <td id="pret4" value=6>6</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" id="cant4"></td>
        <td><textarea name="cost4" id="cost4" rows="1" value=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2></td>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td><textarea name="total" rows="1" readonly value=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" name="calc" value="Caluleaza" onclick="calc()">
</form>
```

It should take the value from the second column, multiply it by the third column, and then by 1.24, and write the result in the forth column. then, this result should be summarized in the last column, of the last row, the total. but it does nothing. i tried different ways, stopped at this one because was the first that came in mind. I also tried assigning object=document.getElementById("cost"+i) then use object.value, but it's the same thing, and it does not work. I can'n find what's wrong.

After comments, whole html looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate()
{
    document.biblioteca.total.value = 0;
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("cost"+i).value= (parseInt(document.getElementById("pret"+i).innerText)*parseFloat(document.getElementById("cant"+i).value))*1.24;
        document.biblioteca.total.value = parseFloat(document.biblioteca.total.value) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("cost"+i).value);
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Biblioteca</h1>


<form name="biblioteca">
<table width=600 border="3">
    <tr>
        <th width="50%">Carte</th>
        <th width="15%">Pret</th>
        <th width="15%">Cantitate</th>
        <th>Cost(TVA inclus)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Manuscrisul gasit la Accra - Paulo Coelho</td>
        <td id="pret1">20</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" id="cant1"></td>
        <td><textarea name="cost1" id="cost1" rows="1" value=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Poarta coliviei - Katie Hickman</td>
        <td id="pret2">10</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" id="cant2"></td>
        <td><textarea name="cost2" id="cost2" rows="1" value=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cincizeci de umbre ale lui Grey - E.L. James </td>
        <td id="pret3">44</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" id="cant3"></td>
        <td><textarea name="cost3" id="cost3" rows="1" value=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ciresarii. Vol.2: Castelul Fetei In Alb - Constantin Chirita</td>
        <td id="pret4">6</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" id="cant4"></td>
        <td><textarea name="cost4" id="cost4" rows="1" value=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2></td>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td><textarea name="total" rows="1" readonly value=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Caluleaza" onclick="calculate()">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

either I;m very tired and can't see some obvious stupid mistake, or there is something fishy....because still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The values stored by those `<input>` elements aren't numbers. They're strings. You need to convert them into floats or integers:

```
var total_element = document.biblioteca.total;

var cost_element = document.getElementById("cost" + i);
var pret_element = document.getElementById("pret" + i);
var cant_element = document.getElementById("cant" + i);

var pret = parseFloat(pret_element.value);
var cant = parseFloat(cant_element.value);

cost_element.value = pret * cant * 1.24;
total_element.value += cost_element.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, you are trying to do math on string values when you are grabbing the value from the input tags.

Also, your function is not running because you can not use calc() as the function name ( for some reason)

Try replacing your code with this.

JS:

```
function calculate()
{
    document.biblioteca.total.value = 0;
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("cost"+i).value= (parseInt(document.getElementById("pret"+i).innerText)*parseFloat(document.getElementById("cant"+i).value))*1.24;
        document.biblioteca.total.value = parseFloat(document.biblioteca.total.value) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("cost"+i).value);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="biblioteca">
<table width=600 border="3">
    <tr>
        <th width="50%">Carte</th>
        <th width="15%">Pret</th>
        <th width="15%">Cantitate</th>
        <th>Cost(TVA inclus)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Manuscrisul gasit la Accra - Paulo Coelho</td>
        <td id="pret1" value="20">20</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" id="cant1"></td>
        <td><textarea name="cost1" id="cost1" rows="1" value=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Poarta coliviei - Katie Hickman</td>
        <td id="pret2" value="10">10</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" id="cant2"></td>
        <td><textarea name="cost2" id="cost2" rows="1" value=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cincizeci de umbre ale lui Grey - E.L. James </td>
        <td id="pret3" value="44">44</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" id="cant3"></td>
        <td><textarea name="cost3" id="cost3" rows="1" value=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ciresarii. Vol.2: Castelul Fetei In Alb - Constantin Chirita</td>
        <td id="pret4" value=6>6</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" id="cant4"></td>
        <td><textarea name="cost4" id="cost4" rows="1" value=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2></td>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td><textarea name="total" rows="1" readonly value=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" name="calc" value="Caluleaza" onclick="calculcate()">
</form>
```

Comment: actually the original function name was calculeaza, and I've tried object.value*1 thinking this would make it int, but seems that there is still some problems, or just an stupid mistake I'm unable to spot right now. I've updated the original post.